# How can applications be installed on SIM and how do I view and disable them?

Tags: privacy, sim-card, mobile-network

I've got a new sim card. After it found the network, soon I've got an sms (supposedly from my [operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_Network_Operator)) saying:

> Dear client! We are installing applications on your sim card for free. Please enable automatic sms sending if necessary.

After about 30 minutes, I've got another sms saying:

> Highway fees, mobile lottery, parking, infoSMS/MMS. Use the 'operator-name-here' menu on your phone if it supports it.

To be clear, I want to opt out. Need none of these and don't like the idea that any applications are auto-installing, not even 'for free'. But I don't even understand what's going on.

1. Can applications even be installed on the sim card?
2. What kind of applications, what's the technical name for them?
3. How do they work basically in technical terms?

   I see no `<operator-name-here> menu` in all applications nor in settings.
4. What standard should my phone support to have this menu?

   The sms said that please enable automatic sms . Since I want to opt-out, I've searched all my settings to *disable* it, but in vain.
5. What is automatic sms sending?
6. How can I disable automatic sms on Android in general, and in 2.1 eclair, specifically?
7. How do I list and view what applications are installed on my SIM?

Comment: Please remember that our site rules are "one question per post", not "any list of questions, how many they might be" :) I tried to sum them up, hope the answer covers it. For detailed questions, better open separate posts.

Comment: @Izzy you are right; I should separate them; although I couldn't grasp how because I don't know what were I talking about exactly. They all try to point to 'how to opt-out', though. Thanks for your kind answer. :)

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to separate that (which is why I first answered, then commented ;) Basically, 1-4+7 make one question ("apps on SIM"), 5+6 another one ("automatic SMS"). You might want to "outsource" 5+6 to another post ("What is...and how to disable") if you need closer information on that topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, apps cannot be installed on SIM. What you describe are rather SIM services. AFAIK you can use those with the "SIM Toolkit" app only (which is where you also should find your `<operator-name-here>`, and where you should be able to see what's installed there).

[image: SIM Toolkit]

As long as you did not actively subscribe to any of those services, they should simply stay dormant and never bother you. Last time I've checked for those must be 10 years ago, on my old Nokia. I never encountered them afterwards, though not (un)installing anything on/from SIM.

Neither I ever heard about "automatic SMS". Even service SMS must be approved by the user before being executed. But as many of those services are rather a kind of "SMS mailing lists", could it be that should mean "please subscribe to one of them"?

Comment: They are here indeed, although not all that was mentioned by the sms, rather some of them new. 'Operator-name-here menu' is not a menu but a title at the top for me - unmodifiable and without alternative. It lists the services in a kind of hierarchy; but no operations like uninstall, remove, unsubscribe, opt-out, etc. is available through menu button or long-pressing.

Comment: I never used them myself, and not even touched that stuff since moving to Android, so I have to pass here. As I wrote, it's at least 10 years ago since I last looked at that stuff. But as long as you didn't actively *subscribe*, you shouldn't be charged. To be on the safe side, talk to your provider to list you all subscribed services, and optionally "lock them all down". He will also be able to send you another services SMS which alters/removes what you don't want, though I doubt he will admit that. In that case, you SIM has "trouble" (invent some), and he should send you a new one :)